# Calculate sum of a column in excel using xlwings python after apply Autofilter

Tags: python, xlwings

I need to calculate sum of values in column H. I have applied autofilter in column E using xlwings python.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2Sm7.png)

I have tried this:

```
first_row_sheet1 = ws.range('B1').row
print(first_row_sheet1)
lastrow_sheet1 = ws.range('B1').end('down').row
print(lastrow_sheet1)
for x in range(first_row_sheet1, lastrow_sheet1+1):
    column_B = ws1.api.Range("H"+str(x)).Value
    print(column_B)
```

Answer (score 0):

Excel has a function called `=AGGREGATE` which can be used through xlwings if required - using the `.api.WorksheetFunction` as one would in VBA.  This will then copy the same action as using the function in Excel.

Where `wb` is the workbook, and `ws` is the worksheet (and you have already defined the row variables):

```
print(wb.app.api.WorksheetFunction.Aggregate(9, 5,
    ws.range(f'H{first_row_sheet1}:H{last_row_sheet1}').api))
```

There are a couple of other methods you could emulate in xlwings, some examples are [here](https://exceltrick.com/how_to/sum-filtered-visible-cells/).

For another example on using the `.api`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64151275/18571565) by Felix Zumstein.

xlwings reads the data of hidden cells.  Alternatively, could you import the data into Python and filter there?